# Return a specific dictionary from an array of dictionaries in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I'm getting an array of dictionaries back from an API that changes in order, and I'm trying to work out how to identify the element that I need.

If I knew which element I needed, I'd do it like this:

```
let DataDictionary = DataArray[0] as NSDictionary
```

But the issue is that the order of the array does not stay the same, so instead of accessing by index, I need to 1) search through the array, 2) return the dictionary with the matching key value pair. Such as: "if 'id = 98765' then return this dictionary" :

```
    for element in DataArray as Array<Dictionary<String,String>> {

        if element["id"] == "987654" {

        println("\(element)")
        }

    }
```

I don't think I can typecast in this way though, and I wouldn't be at all surprised if I'm making a ton of other mistakes as well...

If anyone can provide any guidance on this, that would be amazing. If my explanation is not detailed enough, I'll be happy to provide more details - this is my first Stack Overflow post!

All the best,
oli

Comment: Best and simplest way is to loop through your array, and check if any Dictionary's ID matches your desired ID, and perform ahead..!!

Answer (score 5):

Looping works, as does the `filter` function, but this is what `NSPredicate`s were made for:

```
let array = [
    ["id": "1", "theOne": "no"],
    ["id": "2", "theOne": "no"],
    ["id": "98765", "theOne": "yes"],
    ["id": "4", "theOne": "no"]
]

let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(id == '98765')")!
let theOne = (array as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate).first
```

**Edit**

On second thought, filter is a little less verbose:

```
let theOne = array.filter { $0["id"] == "98765" }.first
```

Answer (score 1):

For swift 3.0 ("filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)"
) updated as below:

```
let array = [
["id": "1", "theOne": "no"],
["id": "2", "theOne": "no"],
["id": "98765", "theOne": "yes"],
["id": "4", "theOne": "no"]
] 
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(id == '98765')")!
let theOne = (array as NSArray).filtered(using: predicate).first
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this can work... haven't tested.

```
var dictionaryId: Int?
for dictionary in DataArray {
   if let dictionary as? NSDictionary {
      dictionaryId = dictionary["id"] as? Int
      if dictionaryId != nil && dictionaryId ==98765
      {
         return dictionary;
      }
   }
}
return nil;
```